# How to move Bokeh chart to back layer in HTML/CSS so it does not cover nav?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bokeh

How do I make it so that when a user clicks the hamburger icon for nav the bokeh chart doesn’t cover the menu?

I have bokeh chart on my website that is always on the top layer. Image below:

[image]

I have tried:

1. adjusting my css with  div.bk-canvas-wrapper{z-index: 0!important;} based on  https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/change-canvas-z-index/1248 recommendation.
2. adjusting the nav z-index to 99999
3. I have downloaded the java cdn (https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.4.3.min.js) and edited all the z-index to 0, just to see if that had any effect, but I got none.

_layouts.html (navbar)

```html
<body>
    <section class="navbar_section">
    <div class="navbar navbar_custom  bg-primary" id="nav_section">
    
        <div class="left_and_middle">
<!-- Stuff to left of hamburger menu -->
        </div>
 
        <img class="mobile-menu" id="mobile-cta" src="../static/images/white-hamburger-menu-icon-24.png" alt="Open Navigation">
 
        <nav>
<!-- Stuff in navbar grey pull out area -->
<!-- I want this to be highest z-index or layer when it's pulled out -->
        </nav>
    </section>
    {% block main %}{% endblock %}
 
<!-- pulls out nav menu when hamburger bar is pulled out -->
<script>
    const mobileBtn = document.getElementById('mobile-cta')
        nav = document.querySelector('nav')
        mobileBtnExit = document.getElementById('mobile-exit');
 
    mobileBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.classList.add('menu-btn');
    })
 
    mobileBtnExit.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.classList.remove('menu-btn');
    })
</script>
 
 
<!-- assign navbar height to --nav-height -->
<script>document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--nav-height', `${document.getElementById("nav_section").offsetHeight}px`);</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Dashboard.html (bokeh)

```html
 {% extends "_layout.html" %}
{% block main %}
<section class="dashboard">
  <div class="tbl_img">

    <div class="table_div">
<!-- Stuff for little table  -->
    </div>

    <div class="bokeh_div">
      {{ div_b|safe }}
    </div>

  </div>
</section>

{{ script_b|safe }}

<script src="../static/bokeh/bokeh-2.4.3.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  Bokeh.set_log_level("info");
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Css (navbar)

```css
 /* Navbar */
section.navbar_section {
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top:0;
    .navbar_custom{
        justify-content: flex-start;
        position: fixed;
        width:100%;
        height: 5rem;
        .nav_left{

        }

        nav.menu-btn{display:block;}
        nav {display: none;}
        .mobile-menu{
            position: absolute;
            cursor: pointer;
            right:1rem;
            height: 5rem;
        }
        nav {
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 99999;
            width: 50%;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            background: var(--bs-gray-500);
            height: 100%;

            ul {
                list-style-type: none;
                padding:2rem 2rem 0 0;
                li{

                    font-size: 2em;
                    a{
                        text-decoration: none;
                        display: block;
                        padding: .5em 10px .5em 0;
                        
                        text-align: right;
                        cursor: pointer;
                        &:hover {font-weight: bold;}
                    }    
                }
            }
            .mobile-menu-exit{
                float: right;
                margin: .5em;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Css (dashboard)

```css
 /* Bokeh Chart */
.bokeh_div{
    flex: 2 0 66%;
    width: 90%;
    border-radius: 2em;
    padding: 1%;
    background-color: #20c997;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
//For Screen wider than 1080
@media only screen and (min-width: 1080px) {

    /* Dashboard */
    .tbl_img {
        padding: 2rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;

        .bokeh_div{
            min-width: 50rem;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the z-index but I was focusing on `nav` when problem was with `section.navbar_section` at the top of my css(navbar).

```css
/* Navbar */
section.navbar_section {
    position: fixed; // <--ADDED HERE
    z-index: 1;      // <--ADDED HERE
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top:0;
    .navbar_custom{
        justify-content: flex-start;
```

In fact, just adding z-index: 1; was sufficient. Also, I was able to remove z-index from `nav` as well.